# Dynamically Loads and Unloads css and scripts jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, responsive-design

I want to load CSS and JS dynamically depending on the screen size of a device or desktop. Is there any way or plugin that would work for this functionality.

So basically, there would be minimum and maximum width of the screen to trigger which stylesheet and script to load and unload. Example on my desktop browser, when i resize the width of my browser, it dynamic loading/unloading of styles and scripts will be triggered.

Also, it should work on loading external/remote stylesheets and scripts.

Thanks :)

Comment: look at [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries)

Answer (score 1):

**Here your Answer**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" class="test">
<script type='text/javascript' src='jquery-1.8.3.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var WindowWidth = $(window).innerWidth();
    if(WindowWidth >= 801){
    $("link.test").attr("href", "applyCss.css");
    return false;
    }
    else if(WindowWidth <= 800){
    $("link.test").attr("href", "applyCss-two.css");
    return false;
    }
});
$(window).resize(function() {
    var WindowWidth = $(window).innerWidth();
    if(WindowWidth >= 801){
    $("link.test").attr("href", "applyCss.css");
    return false;
    }
    else if(WindowWidth <= 800){
    $("link.test").attr("href", "applyCss-two.css");
    return false;
    }
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

if you have different css files for different screns  better you merge them, and run media queries.
both Jquery and CSS have its own method of media queries.
 for example :

```
CSS Media Queries-



 @media all and (max-width: 699px) and (min-width: 520px){
      body {
        background-color: green;
        color:white;
      }
    }
    @media all and (max-width: 700px) and (min-width: 1180px){
      body {
        background: black;
        color:yellow;
      }
    }

Jquery:
<script>


$(document).ready(function(){
css_small={
    "background-color":"green",
    "color":"white"
    }
    css_big={
    "background-color":"black",
    "color":"yello"
    }

    if($(window).width <699 && $(window).width >520){
    $(body).css(css_small);
    }
    if($(window).width <1180 && $(window).width >700){
    $(body).css(css_big);
    }
})
$(window).resize(function(){
css_small={
    "background-color":"green",
    "color":"white"
    }
    css_big={
    "background-color":"black",
    "color":"yello"
    }

    if($(window).width <699 && $(window).width >520){
    $(body).css(css_small);
    }
    if($(window).width <1180 && $(window).width >700){
    $(body).css(css_big);
    }
})
</script>
```

I hope this is what you are looking for..
and yes don't forget to add jquery link

Answer (score 0):

It would be better that you change the classes and ids dynamically and let the css do its work.

```
  $('#MyElement').addClass('MyClass');
```

First detect the kind of display and accordingly assign class